# How many times "2" occurs in all numbers from 0 to n

Tags: algorithm, math, language-agnostic

> find how many times  "2" occurs in all numbers from 0 to n .

example : `n`= 112      `answer` = 22

```
numbers : 2 , 12 , 20-29 , 32 ...  92 , 102 ,  112
```

I came up with the following method :

let `k`= number of digits of n

`f(k)` = number of two's from `0` to `10^k-1` ..

> f(1) = 1     //    2
>   f(2) = 10*f(1)+ 10^(2-1) // 12 , 20 - 29 , 32 ... 92
>   f(3) = 10*f(2)+ 10^(3-1)
>   and so on ...

```
twos(int n , int k)
{
    if(n<2)
        return 0;
    else if(n<10)
        return 1;

    msb = n/10^k
    remainder = n%10^k

    if(msb==2) // eg 230 ,  calculate 200 ... to 230  , and find twos from 0 on 199  and recursion on 30
        return msb*(f(k)) + (remainder+1) + twos(remainder) // 2*(below 100) + 31 + tows(30)
    else if (msb>=3)
         return msb*(f(k)) + (10^k) + twos(remainder)  // for 312 -> 3*(below 100) + 100 + twos(12)
    else
        return  msb*(f(k)) + twos(remainder)

}
```

Is my approach correct ?
If so , is there any solution faster than this ?

**EDIT** :
My approach seems correct for these test cases ,   [here](http://ideone.com/ewOc49) is simulation
`results` :
1st coloumn : n ,  2nd coloumn : brute force  , 3rd coloumn : my method

> 2  1  1
>   5  1  1
>   91  19  19
>   868  277  277
>   7783  3359  3359
>   55576  32718  32718
>   293911  242093  242093
>   10179297  7091858  7091858
>   59939789  51975959  51975959

Comment: For the correctness, did you check with a dumb loop ?

Comment: a loop gives runtime error with n=10^7 , here n can be till 10^18

Comment: you can always compare the results of your solution with the results of a brute-force implementation. it cannot in theory prove that your solution is correct for *every input*, but it can give some confidence...

Comment: @aseem: the idea is to test it with small numbers... eg: does it give correct results for all n<10000 ?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: done as you said , seems correct for random cases

Comment: The answer is exactly 0 for all *n* as long as you stick to base-2 ;p

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a request for a code review.

Comment: @Raedwald: i am not asking for code , just the algorithm , the code i have posted is to show what i have done . Please take some time to read the post carefully .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say the number consists of digits `n=... n4 n3 n2 n1`.   We want to look at all numbers `x<=n` and count the digits `2` within them.  `x` shall be represented as `x=... x4 x3 x2 x1`.  As a start, we count how many numbers have a 2 as last digit, `x1==2`:

```
f1(n) = (n+8) / 10
```

assuming the division truncates.  Some examples:

```
f1(1) = 0
f1(2) = 1
f1(12) = 2
f1(21) = 2
f1(22) = 3
```

Now let's count the numbers that have a 2 as second to last digit, `x2==2`.  This is similar to cutting of the last digit of `n` and then counting the numbers that have a two as last digit:

```
f2(n) = 10 * f1(n/10)  # almost right
```

Let's test it:

```
f2(10) = 0
f2(20) = 10 * f1(2) = 10  # wrong
f2(25) = 10 * f1(2) = 10  # wrong
f2(29) = 10 * f1(2) = 10  
f2(30) = 10 * f1(3) = 10
```

We need special handling for the case when the second to last digit of `n` is a two itself, `n2==2`:

```
f2(n) = 10*f1(n/10) - 9 + n1 # if n2==2
```

With `n1 == n % 10` (remainder function) this can be written as:

```
f2(n) = 10*f1(n/10) - 9 + n%10 # if n2==2
```

Similarly for counting the numbers where `x3==2`:

```
f3(n) = 100*f1(n/100) # if n3 != 2
f3(n) = 100*f1(n/100) - 99 + n%100 # if n3 == 2
```

Summing it all up we get for the total number of 2's:

```
f(n) = f1(n) + f2(n) + f3(n) + ...
```

In Java:

```
public static int count2(int n) {
    int res = (n+8) / 10;
    int divider = 10;
    while (n>= 2*divider){
        int na = n / divider;
        res = res + divider * ((na+8) /10);
        if (na%10==2)
             res = res - divider + 1 + n % divider;
        divider = divider * 10;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let `f(k)` be the number of appearances of the digit 2 in numbers from 0 to `10^k-1` (i.e. up to k-digit numbers).
Note that when increasing the digits from k-1 to k, we have f(k-1) appearances for every one of the new leading digit, plus 10^(k-1) appearances in the leading digit itself:

```
f(k) = 10*f(k-1) + 10^(k-1)
```

(Which is exactly your formula)

Solving this recurrence gives:

```
f(k) = k * 10^(k-1)
```

For example:

```
f(1) = 1
f(2) = 20
f(3) = 300
f(4) = 4000
...
```

There's actually a different way to get this formula. Consider all k-digit numbers (where missing leading digits are replaced with zeroes). The number of numbers is 10^k, and we have k digits in each, therefore we have a total of `k*10^k` digits. Now, every possible digit appears the same number of times, which is `k*10^k / 10 = k*10^(k-1)`.

**-- EDIT --**

The following Java solution uses the formula above, and solves the problem for an arbitrary n in O(log n) time:

```
// Counts occurrences of digit 2 in numbers less than n
public static int count(int n) {
  int count = 0;
  int factor = 1;
  int pos = 0;
  while (true) {
    int m = n / factor;
    if (m == 0) //Past last digit
      break;
    int d = m % 10;      

    count += d * pos * factor / 10; 

    if (d == 2)
      count += n % factor;
    else if (d > 2) {
      count += factor; 
    }

    factor = 10 * factor;
    pos++;
  }

  return count;
}
```

Comment: this much part i got correct , but fails when n is not power of 10

Comment: @aseem: of course it fails, because f(k) is defined to count occurrences in the range 0..10^k-1. You'll have to do extra work to handle any number.

Comment: well, that was the task. I don't see how this answers the question.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: I'm not sure I understand. The OP asked whether his approach is correct, and how his calculation can be made more efficient. I addressed both questions, I think.

Comment: gives wrong answer for certain cases http://ideone.com/ewOc49 . Btw , thanks for the explaination .

Comment: @aseem: No, it doesn't. Remember that my version counts the number of 2 from 0 to n-1.